# gcc: cross-referencing class compilation

Tags: compilation, incomplete-type

if got a quite simple question (at least I hope so), but I cannot figure out what to do to tell g++ in what order to "complete" my classes. I reduced it to this simple example:

base.h:

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

#include "otherclass.h"
class otherclass;

class base {
    public:
        base(otherclass* other);

    protected:
        otherclass* m_other;
};

#endif /* BASE_H_ */
```

derived.h:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H_
#define DERIVED_H_

#include "base.h"

class derived : public base {
    public:
        derived(otherclass* other);
};

#endif /* DERIVED_H_ */
```

(both corresponding .cpp files only contain constructors which assign the given otherclass* to the member variables)

otherclass.h:

```
#ifndef OTHERCLASS_H_
#define OTHERCLASS_H_

#include "derived.h"

class otherclass {
    public:
        otherclass( );

    protected:
        derived* m_derived;
};

#endif /* OTHERCLASS_H_ */
```

otherclass.cpp:

```
#include "otherclass.h"

otherclass::otherclass() {
    m_derived = new derived(this);
}
```

Since it may be relevant I'll paste the entire output of scons:

```
g++ -o base.o -c base.cpp
g++ -o derived.o -c derived.cpp
In file included from otherclass.h:4:0,
             from base.h:4,
             from base.cpp:1:
derived.h:8:29: error: expected class-name before '{' token
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
In file included from base.h:4:0,
             from derived.h:4,
             from derived.cpp:1:
otherclass.h:11:3: error: 'derived' does not name a type
```

So it looks like base is an unknown type to gcc at this point and pre-declaring it obviously makes it cry since deriving from an incomplete type is forbidden.

I really don't see the problem here (except for the error message of course).

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Searching using google for my problem didn't help me, but the related questions tab in stackoverflow did ;)

For reference, the solution is this:

In header files if you only have pointers to a class you should

1. predeclare the class (that's what I did before), like

   class otherclass;

   in base.h and derived.h, and

   class derived;

   in otherclass.h, but
2. do *not* include the corresponding header files. *Only* include them in their .cpp files (that's what I failed at).

Explanation: Since pointers are always of the same size and their target type is only relevant if you actually work with (i.e. dereference) them, it totally suffices for gcc to accept a derived* if you tell it about the existence of the identifier "derived" (i.e. predeclaration). In fact you are fine if you avoid *any* inclusion of (own) header files whose type is only used in such a way (does not need to be complete).